# Lambda and Cloudfront URL rewrite

Tags: javascript

what is the proper way to rewrite url from cloudfront cdn by using only lambda, 
for example https://domain/channel/?id=12345 to https://domain/channel/12345

Are there any special tricks ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say lambda, do you mean a lambda expression or AWS lambda? Or something else?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, its AWS lambda

Comment: Okay, I'll undelete my answer as you can run JS on Lambda.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use a Lambda@Edge function.

In order to quickly remove the querystring identifier, use the following.
You would run this as a "visitor request" python lambda and deploy it to your cloudfront distribution.

This way, it wouuld look at the querystring, perform a replace on the value, then   do a 302 redirect. That way, your Cloudfront distribution can still utilize the cache properties at the edge location, and not have to make multiple requests to your origin.

```py
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlencode

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']

    print("Query string: ", request["querystring"])

    id = request["querystring"].replace('?id=', '')

    response = {
        'status': '302',
        'statusDescription': 'Found',
        'headers': {
            'location': [{
                'key': 'Location',
                 'value': https://domain/channel/id
             }]
        }
    }
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var domain = https://domain/channel/?id=12345;
var replaced = domain.replace('?id=', '');
console.log(replaced);
```

This will log:

```
https://domain/channel/12345
```

Comment: does this work the opposite way, let say if user request https://domain/channel/12345, can it be redirectred to only https://domain/channel

Comment: in nginx it should be:

 rewrite ^/channel/(.*)$ /link.php?di=$1 last;

but, i'm totally under cdn with static html. Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't understand your second question. In regards to the first, you would need different code to do that.

Comment: to rewrite user request https://domain/channel/i1234 into https://domain/channel?i=1234 so static html / js can parse it easily without using php/nginx/etc (only static html) in cdn environment?

is that possible?

many thanks for your reply